# SPSS: Regression Sample Size

Tags: regression, spss

I just wanted to know where I can see my sample size in the output of a linear regression. It must be in the ANOVA-Table in the column of the df. Is my sample size 487?

*ANOVA-Table*
Regression       2
Residual Error  485
Total           487

Comment: Why not compare that output with what you know about your data?

Comment: I have missing values. My sample size is 500 but not everyone has answered my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Total row of the ANOVA table df column is the size of the sample used (+1 for the constant term, if you have one).  You can also include something like
/DESCRIPTIVES MEAN STDDEV CORR SIG N
in the Regression syntax (or check Descriptives in the Statistics subdialog) to see the sample size and other statistics.

Comment: What do you mean by : "+1 for the constant term, if you have one"
In my Anova-Table is only in the column df Regression:2, Residual Error: 485, Total:487. So my sample size is 487, isn't it?

Comment: The regression sum of squares will have one fewer df than the number of coefficients to account for the constant term.  If you suppress the constant, you can see the effect.  But the descriptives output will show you the number of cases actually used by the regression.